# Client-side only AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, server, client-side

I am a little confused about how to run an AngularJS app.

Let me explain: my team and I are trying to make a project that will have a web service that the client side uses (written in JavaScript+HTML in AngularJS ), my problem is with the client side (some basic understanding).

I have seen the angular example but I don't want to use node and I have a little problem understanding something; how can I start my app(only the client side)?

1. how can I start it on my local computer so that the routing and everything will work without nodejs(because it doesnt work with file:// )
2. in general how can I start a site like this on a server with out something like node.

This is no my first website just in this format I never did from scratch and
I think I am missing some basic understanding I tried to research it but got all confused.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  The fundamentals can be a bit confusing.  First thing to do is lots of research, to understand those basics and clear the confusion.  Once you have a start on your project, SO is great for asking specific programming questions (this one will probably be closed as "not a programming question," don't take it personally.) Here's a starting point:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: PS: you may also be confusing server-side, client-side, and "Single Page Applications."  Google "Single Page Application" for more background.

Comment: I know the difference between a server and client side Its not my first program  its just that I never build one from scratch ... 
I just need to know how to get my app to work on my local computer because in chrome without server it dooesnt work and in generak how it is working on a server .

Comment: In order to run a web application you are going to need a web server to host it, locally or publicly.  using node.js along with express is a quick way to host an application and get you developing with angular.  If you are still completely against all things node, another suggestion would be to try Microsoft Visual Studio which has it all integrated for you.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

> how can I start it on my local computer so that the routing and everything will work without nodejs(because it doesnt work with file:// )

Install a webserver

> in general how can I start a site like this on a server with out something like node.

Install a webserver that isn't one you wrote using NodeJS. There are plenty out there.

Answer (score 0):

- You can do on your local computer using `xampp` or `wamp server`.
- Same code will work on other server also like `godaddy`s etc.

**NOTE:** Use `relative path` instead of `absolute path.`